# Maximum email attachment size with SMTP?

Tags: smtp, mime

I have a program that will be sending a large output. I am just wondering what the max email attachment size is? According to [RFC 1870](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1870) a mail server can reject messages because they are too large, but is there a max size when using SMTP/MIME? I can't find anything on this! The biggest I've heard people sending is 25mb.

Comment: My company allows clients to set their own limits and one has 400MB as do most of their clients/partners. Big companies deal with a lot bigger data than regular home users.

Answer (score 5):

the relevant RFC is RFC 2821 (SMTP). Find it at http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt .

See section "4.5.3.1 Size limits and minimums"

it says there (with targeted audience the implementers of the SMTP protocol):

> message size restrictions should be avoided if at all possible

That doesn't mean that in practice such restrictions are not there as a result of implementation choices, or as a result of an intentional restriction through the configuration of that mail server.

Note, also, that attachments are (protocol-wise) just part of the message. These are coded in by e-mail clients.

Comment: The OP had a typo.  The relevant spec is RFC 1870, which specifies how a server can advertise the max size allowed for an email.

Answer (score 2):

I have customer's that send out 100meg emails of GIS images.  The only limitation is the size of the SMTP server imposes.

Comment: That's true, and the situation has greatly improved with SMTP extensions such as byte-encoding, chunking and checkpointing. However, in practice, most email providers limit the size of the whole email (Yahoo! 40MB, Gmail 25MB). See also [Maximum Attachment Size Mail Services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26986898/maximum-attachment-size-mail-services)

Answer (score 2):

Many mail servers impose a restriction on how large messages they will accept, but this is a per-server setting. You can find the limit if the server implements the ESMTP SIZE extension (most do).  This is documented in detail in the RFC you are referring to.

There is no mechanism to limit the size of any individual attachment, nor does it make any sense from the protocol's point of view to do that. If the server has enough disk space to store the message, it can accept it; it doesn't know or care how the message is structured into individual parts, and anyway, as far as SMTP is concerned, it's just a collection of contiguous bytes.

Comment: That's the limit of the whole message, not of attachments.

Comment: @rds Of course. The maximum attachment size is the maximum message size minus the overhead of the containing message.

Comment: It's not so obvious. Exchange (EAS) defines a different limit for the max attachment size.

Comment: The question is about limits in the SMTP standard, not what Microsoft does or doesn't do.

Comment: Do you imply I should downvote your answer, because it doesn't answer the question "Maximum email attachment size with SMTP?"